# Regex to find common typos in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to make a regular expression to find common typos such as multiple spaces between words, accidentally accidentally repeated words, or multiple exclamation marks at the end of sentences.

```
def f(m):
    return m.group(1)
a=re.compile(r'(?P<name>(\D+|\s))(?P=name)+')
b=a.sub(f,'text text text text and hi hi hipo !!!       1234 ')
print(b)
```

I want to display on the screen: `text text and hi hipo ! 1234`
but I still can't fix the problem of multiple spaces between words.

I hope you guys can help me fix this problem.

Comment: Your `def f` makes little sense since you just return the Group 1 value. A `\g<name>` would do the same in the string replacement pattern. The inner parentheses in Group "name" are redundant here.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew do you have another way to fix this for me?

Comment: The requirements are unclear. Why is the `'text text and hipo ! 1234 '` expected and not `'text and hipo ! 1234 '`?

Comment: because if it's even, then show it in half and  if it's odd then show once

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew: I mainly want to solve the problem of multiple spaces between words

Comment: Then, it would look like `re.sub(r'([^\d\s]+)(?:\s*\1+)+|(\s)\2+', r'\1\2', s)` (Python 3.5+)

Comment: sorry about some of I wrote above,i want to display ' text and hi hipo ! 1234' not 'text and hipo ! 1234 '

Comment: See https://ideone.com/RSpHPJ